# Parallel consumer with spring boot

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm currently testing how the parallel-consumer library (https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) behaves. However, I've encountered an issue while setting up the factory container customizer. I want to set my message listener, which is of type ParallelStreamProcessor. However, the method setupMessageListener only expects AcknowledgingMessageListener or MessageListener.
Is there any way to address this? One option is to create a customized listener by extending one of the existing listeners, but I'm open to other solutions.

```
/**
     * Set the message listener; must be a {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener}
     * or {@link org.springframework.kafka.listener.AcknowledgingMessageListener}.
     * @param messageListener the listener.
     */
    public void setMessageListener(Object messageListener) {
        this.messageListener = messageListener;
        adviseListenerIfNeeded();
    }
```

This is how I am creating beans

```
@Bean
  public ParallelStreamProcessor<String, String> parallelStreamProcessor(Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer) {

    ParallelConsumerOptions<String, String> options = ParallelConsumerOptions.<String, String>builder()
        .ordering(ParallelConsumerOptions.ProcessingOrder.KEY)
        .maxConcurrency(16)
        .commitMode(ParallelConsumerOptions.CommitMode.PERIODIC_CONSUMER_SYNC)
        .consumer(kafkaConsumer)
        .build();

    return ParallelStreamProcessor.createEosStreamProcessor(options);
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
      ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory,
      ParallelStreamProcessor<String, String> parallelStreamProcessor) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);

    factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
      container.setupMessageListener(parallelStreamProcessor);
      container.setAutoStartup(true);
    });

    return factory;
  }
```

I expect alternate solution to resolve this issue.